# How to write exponential summation notation with the exponent is $\sum_{n=0}^{10} 2^n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

I have this series:
$3^{2047} + 3^{2046} + 3^{2045} + \cdots + 3^2 + 3^1 + 1$

$2047$ is the highest exponent that I found from $1+2+4+\cdots+1024$, which is the sum of $2^n$ with $n=0, 1, 2, \ldots,10$.
 I know that it is $\sum_{n=0}^{10} 2^n = 2047$

How to write in sigma notation for the sum of $3^k$, with $k$ runs from $0$ to $\sum_{n=0}^{10} 2^n = 2047$?

Is this correct?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\sum_{n=0}^{10}2^n} 3^k$$

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That looks nasty, but is correct. I'm not sure what you're looking to use it for, but I'll point out it's geometric anyway, which means you can simplify it into a nicer form.

Comment: But why don't you just use the actual number for your upper bound?  Why write it as a sum?

Comment: Maybe introduce a dummy variable $t=\sum_{n=0}^{10}2^n$. So the sum runs from $0$ to $t$

Comment: Actually it is not the exact question. The question is write the product of (3^1 + 1)(3^2 + 1)...(3^1024 +1) in exponential notation. The product I found is 3^2047 + 3^2046 + ...+ 1. I want to write the exponential notation that reflects the original question, I mean to include the sum of 2^n.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will write as you suggested.

Comment: Is the product $\prod^{1024}_{i=1}(3^{i}+1)$ or $\prod^{10}_{i=0}(3^{(2^i)}+1)$? And presumably you mean 'summation notation' rather than 'exponential notation'?

Comment: The product is the second one, ∏ 3(2i)+1

Comment: Have you considered that $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1}-1$?